# how to insert new rows only ibm datastage

Tags: datastage, ibm-infosphere

I'm trying to insert new rows only, i already tried with the insert new rows only in write mode options for the `JDBC` stage, but it doesn't work, it also inserts the old rows too. Maybe this is because in the column table i have `id` and `created_at` (getdate()) so although the rows of the old file already inserted, the db assumes it's new because of the `id` and `created_at` will be different each time i run the job. How do i insert only new rows only (that has not been stored in the database) of the excel to the database ignoring the `id` and `created_at` columns?

Answer (score 1):

Typically you would perform a lookup against the target table in DataStage, and proceed to insert only if the lookup fails (via the Reject output of the Lookup stage).

Comment: ah i see, could you please detail your answer Ray? i'm still new to Data Stage. What will the connection look like?